# Installation of wifi dongle in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, huawei

I am trying to install huewai wifi dongle in my hp prodesk400 G2 MT model desktop installed with Ubuntu 12.04, but remain unsuccessful. I am quite new. Please help anybody.

Comment: give us output of "lsusb" command

Comment: refer this http://telecomtalk.info/step-by-step-guide-configuring-usb-modem-ubuntu/101849/

Comment: What did you try so far and where did it go wrong? Were there any error messages? What's the USB device ID of the dongle? You can list USB devices and their IDs with the command `lsusb`. Please [edit] your question to add the device ID or other relevant information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.